# Declaring class level variable in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have started playing with Scala so my code is a bit Java-ish. Below is my code :

```
object TypeParam extends App{

  class Param1[T](val elem: T*){
    val elems : List[T] = elem.toList
    def toPrint(): Unit ={
      elems.foreach(print)
    }
  }

  @Override
  def main(args : List[String]): Unit ={
    val x= new Param1[Int](1,2,3,4,6,7)
    x.toPrint()
  }
}
```

what I am expecting is to get the elements printed but in realty I am not getting any output.

I know that I can print a list easily through `forEach` but for learning I am trying to blend things up.

Could anyone explain why I am not getting any output,so in scala do we not have class level variable which can be set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using below syntax you are not overriding `main` method from `App` trait, hence you do not see any output.

```
@Override
def main(args : List[String]): Unit ={
```

Use below syntax to override `main` method:

```
override def main(args: Array[String]) {
```

*Note* use of `override` keyword. In Scala, it's a mandatory to use `override` when overriding a concrete method.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with `main` method.
As you're overriding `App` `trait` you can put code, you want to execute, in the body of class itself, instead of creating specific method.

Original `main` in App looks slightly different:

`def main(args : scala.Array[scala.Predef.String]) : scala.Unit`

Comment: Yeah it got fixed. Thanks.